# Javascript string evaluation

Tags: javascript

There is a portuguese IT company that is looking for some developers in a few areas and just out of curiosity (since I already have a job, thankfully) I went to check the job postings.

When I went to check out the JS developer posting, they provided a piece of JS code that caught my attention. I've worked for some time with JS and I find myself getting back to programming with JS from time to time but to be honest I've never seen anything even similar to the code given.

This is the code:

```
!(function(x){
    '6D 61 6E'.split(' ').forEach(function(a){
        x+=String.fromCharCode(parseInt(a,16));
    });
    return x;
})('');
```

I went and wrote this on Chrome's JS console and the output is 'false'.
If I understand it correctly, the "strange" code, and according to the ASCII table reads 'm a n', and parseInt is supposed to return an integer based on a hexadecimal radix. It then gets converted once again into a string, this time based on the chars decimal value.
To finish it all, we evaluate the return 'x' by "negating it" (not the word I was looking for but can't remember a better one at the time... evaluate maybe?).

Then, why is the output false? If we don't evaluate the return the result is the expected one 'man', but I don't see why we get false on this particular instance.

Anyone care to elaborate?

Comment: What does that have to do with `addEventListener()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn My mistake, I had SO open to ask another question which I didn't come to complete and forgot to change the title.. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you seem to have worked out,

```
return x;
```

...will return the string "man". But your question seems to boil down to why `!"man"` gives `false`?

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators), logical not `!`:

> *Returns `false` if its single operand can be converted to `true`; otherwise, returns `true`.*

The empty string `""` is falsey, so `!""` is `true`, but any other string is truthy, so `!"any other string"` is `false`.

Comment: @nnnnnn I came to post this question as I've tried using other strings instead of the empty string and I still got false as an output, but I'm quite sure that your explanation is the right one